# Adding ChildViewController with NavigationController into ContainerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am designing a custom `UIViewContainerController` for a project. I keep a `contentView` in this container to manage my `Childviewcontroller's` views. When I add a `childviewcontroller` alone it works fine. But some of the `childviewcontrollers` must be initialized with a "navigationcontroller" & that is where I'm having problems with implementation.

I use the usual `initWithRootViewController` method on "navigationcontroller" to init(initialize) my "childvc" & then how do I add this along with the navigation bar to my `contentView`?

This is the code I'm using for "childvc" without a "navigationcontroller" & it works fine.

```
// in my containerview controller's add childview method. 
ChildViewController1 *vc = [ChildViewController1 new];

[self addChildViewController:vc]; // self = container vc
vc.view.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
[self.contentView addSubview:vc.view]; // contentView is the space i've kept to add childvcs
[vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Now when I try to use a "childvc" initialized with "navigationcontroller" (because there is a flow to this "childvc") I get errors & what I need to know is how do I add this to my `contentView` along with navigation bar. (just like in a tabbarcontroller).

This is the code I use to initialize "childvc" with "nav controller" :

```
ChildViewController1 *vc = [ChildViewController1 new];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
```

I've made public repository with simple project "[Here](http://goo.gl/f9xTVs)".

I have read doc of tab bar / nav controllers & creating custom  container viewcontrollers in apple documentation but seems to be missing something critical.
Link is "[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)".

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the commented code in your public repo, what you are trying to do is this:

```
container VC
  +-- navigation VC
  |     +-- child VC
  +-- child VC
```

This is wrong, the child VC can appear only once in the view controller hierarchy. Your hierarchy should look like this:

```
container VC
  +-- navigation VC
        +-- child VC
```

Here's a rough sketch of how the code for setting this up might look like. Notice how the navigation controller (and its view) completely replaces the `ChildViewController1`.

```
// Setup the view controller hierarchy - place this inside
// your container VC's initializer
ChildViewController1* vc = [ChildViewController1 new];
// With this statement, vc becomes the child of the navigation controller
UINavigationController* nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
[self.childViewControllers addObject:nav];
[nav didMoveToParentViewController:self];

// Setup the view hierarchy - place this inside your
// container VC's loadView override
nav.view.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
[self.contentView addSubview:nav.view];
```

As mentioned in the comments, I suggest that you separate the setup of the view controller hierarchy from the setup of the view hierarchy.

- A typical place for the view controller setup is during initialization. You can see how `UINavigationController` does this with its `initWithRootViewController:` initializer.
- The canonical place for the view hierarchy setup is in the view controller's `loadView` override.